# Java - fix lambda expression either with version or conversion

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am trying to add a custom capacitor plugin to my android app. Works for iOS, currently I am integrating it into android.

I am no Java developer, my Java knowledge is fairly old.
The build step of the app that builds the plugin alongside throws

```
        request.addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                                           ^
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
```

1. Where can I amp up my Java version to 8 in my ionic project to build with lambdas?
2. How could I make this compatible with `-source 7` ?

```
        Activity activity = this.cordova.getActivity();
        ReviewManager manager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(activity);
        Task<ReviewInfo> request = manager.requestReviewFlow();


        request.addOnCompleteListener(task -> {

            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                ReviewInfo reviewInfo = task.getResult();
                Task<Void> flow = manager.launchReviewFlow(activity, reviewInfo);
                flow.addOnCompleteListener(launchTask -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        callbackContext.success();
                    } else {
                        Exception error = task.getException();
                        callbackContext.error("Failed to launch review - " + error.getMessage());
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Exception error = task.getException();
                callbackContext.error("Failed to launch review flow - " + error.getMessage());
            }

        });
```

The code is based on
https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/kotlin-java#java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the Java version for the project.

It's in `build.gradle`

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support

Comment: Thanks!  No `android` in my file? 
```

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

apply from: "variables.gradle"

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Fixed, I had to adjust the `build.gradle` in the plugin. Thanks!